# How can I fetch specific rows from a Parse class with indexes? (Parse.Promise.when bug?)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In Parse, let's say I have 1000 rows of `Bar`. Say I want to find the rows at specific 'positions' based on when the row was created.

What I've tried:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var indexes = [1,2,3];

var query = new Parse.Query('Bar');
query.addAscending('createdAt');  // oldest first for predictable ordering
var promises = indexes.map((i) => {
    var q = _.clone(query);
    q.skip(i);
    return q.first();
});

Parse.Promise.when(promises)
    .done((results) => {
        console.log(results); // returns ONE row only.
    });
```

I was expecting an array of results, of all the `first()` promises' results. Alas, I cannot understand why `Parse.Promise.when` only returns one result.

Comment: It turns out that there is a mismatch in the documented behaviour of Parse.Promise.when():

See the following two issues
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/114 https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/158

Comment: It looks like 1.6.x has this issue. Fixed in 1.7.